# How to install MySQL for python WITHOUT internet access

Tags: python, mysql

I want to install MySQL-python-1.2.5 on an old Linux (Debian) embedded system.
Python is already installed together with a working MariaDB/MySQL database.

Problems: 
1) the system is managed remotely and has no direct internet access;
2) band is infinitesimal to install further apps/libraries, so I would avoid doing this if possible;
3) gcc and mysql_config not installed.

My question: is there any possibility to add the MYSQL-PYTHON package already READY to be imported into a python script, compiled and as a single file even better, without going through a painful and local upgrade?
My dream: prepare the working package/file on my local PC and then transfer it using SCP.

Note: the remote system and my working pc are compatible and I don't need any special toolchain.

Comment: have you tried the .deb files from here https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-mysqldb

Comment: Please mark it as answer below cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried the .deb files from here packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-mysqldb

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you satch_boogie
(As a comment I couldn't upvote)

Comment: there is "Mark it as answer(faded tick mark)" near the Answer